# How to select product category while adding new product in woocommerce?

Tags: categories, search, woocommerce-offtopic

I am beginner in wordpress. I have WooCommerce website & have hundreds of product categories. I want to assign related category to the product while adding it, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can see product categories on the right sidebar below Update / Publish section.

[image]

If you cant see the categories go to the top of the page on the right find & click **Screen Options** and check **Product Categories**

[image]

Comment: I can see categories but i need to search categories because we have thousand categories and sub-categories inside it.