# How To Hide A Post

Tags: posts

I have a static front page on my WordPress blog, and currently all posts appear on my designated "posts page".

How can I prevent any post appearing on the "posts page" if I so chose?

I've looked at plugins which seem to work if your blog is on the 'front page' but don't work on the 'posts page'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can save your post as "Draft" or "Pending" and that post will not be appear on front end side.

Comment: I want to publish the post. I just don't want it to appear with other posts on the "posts page".

Comment: simplest way is to assign a category to that post and don't call that category where you don't want to.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani - that's my question really. How do  achieve what you've described? Phil

Comment: that's really simple thing [see this similar setting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253951/how-to-select-product-category-while-adding-new-product-in-woocommerce/253955#253955) to assign category to your post, if you are using Visual Composer, search how to show posts by category.

Comment: what criteria do you want to use to decide whether to show the post?  If it is some characteristic of the post (e.g., a specific value of a specific post_meta, or a specific term being applied), then you can add a `parse_query` filter...but without more info it's hard to give a detailed answer.